# Inserting values into a json array at a specific position in java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am getting a json array as a string from one activity to the other using intent extras.How can I insert a value at a certain position in the json array in java.
This is the json array that I am using.

```
{"result":[{"itembarcode":"BRMS","weight":"10","gross_wt":"1","stone_amt":"0","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"100","qty":"1","net_rate":"32100.0","item_total":"32100.0","sum_total":"64600.0"},
{"itembarcode":"MSAA0015","weight":"10","gross_wt":"11","stone_amt":"100000","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"500","qty":"1","net_rate":"32500.0","item_total":"32500.0","sum_total":"64600.0"}]}
```

And I would like to insert a doc_no inside this array something like

```
   {"result":[{"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"BRMS","weight":"10","gross_wt":"1","stone_amt":"0","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"100","qty":"1","net_rate":"32100.0","item_total":"32100.0","sum_total":"64600.0"},
    {"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"MSAA0015","weight":"10","gross_wt":"11","stone_amt":"100000","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"500","qty":"1","net_rate":"32500.0","item_total":"32500.0","sum_total":"64600.0"}]}
```

I have tried something like this

```
 try {
            JSONArray jr = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int j=0;j<tot_length; j++)
            {
                JSONObject jb = jr.getJSONObject(j);
                String docnumber = "IN1001";
                jb.put("doc_no",docnumber);
            }
            Log.d("NEW JSON",json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it did not work for me.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: obviously `Log.d("NEW JSON",json);`  it is not showing new json ... new json is  `jr.toString()`

Comment: How are you sending and retrieving those values in intent?? Can you provide that piece of code?

Comment: you can insert it using jsonObj.put("doc_no","IN1001"); position doesn't matter since the guy who is going to use it will get the value from key

Comment: exactly thats why I asked how are you sending and retrieving :D

Comment: I am sending data to my php script using google's volley library. @JimitPatel

Comment: Ok then make a model (getter/setter) class for the same. When you get this data from server, parse it and pass the ArrayList to another activity, then you can add/remove/modify it easily.

Comment: From Activity A to Activity B I have sent the data using intent extras.I just want to know how I can parse and insert data at a particular position can any one help with a code sample.I am new to programming.Thank you.

Comment: @Selvin I tried jr.toString() but the problem is nothing is getting logged.Can you help?

Comment: create new JSONArray object ... in the loop add jb to this new array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONObject has no support for manage ordering .. so you need to use library like [GSON](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

i have done this using GSON ..

lets try

```
 try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result"); 
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            LinkedHashMap<String,String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            JSONObject innerJosonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.getString(i));

            // you need to put all values from jsonObject to map for managing the order.. 

            linkedHashMap.put("doc_no","Custom Value");
            linkedHashMap.put("itembarcode",innerJosonObject.getString("itembarcode"));
            linkedHashMap.put("weight",innerJosonObject.getString("weight"));
            linkedHashMap.put("gross_wt", innerJosonObject.getString("gross_wt"));
            //..................... rest of others......
            linkedHashMap.put("sum_total",innerJosonObject.getString("sum_total"));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            // convert linkedHashMap to json string and it will keep the insertion order..
            String string = gson.toJson(linkedHashMap,LinkedHashMap.class);
            jsonArray.put(i,string);
        }
        jsonObject.put("result",jsonArray);
        Log.e("json",jsonObject.toString());
       // this prints jsonArray only [............]
        Log.e("json_array", jsonArray.toString());


    }catch (Exception e){

    }




 Output:`{"result":["{\"doc_no\":\"Custom Value\",\"itembarcode\":\"BRMS\",\"weight\":\"10\",\"gross_wt\":\"1\",\"sum_total\":\"64600.0\"}",
                    "{\"doc_no\":\"Custom Value\",\"itembarcode\":\"MSAA0015\",\"weight\":\"10\",\"gross_wt\":\"11\",\"sum_total\":\"64600.0\"}"]}`
```

Add this to gradle file

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])    
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    }
```

Hope it helps .. Thank You

Comment: Thank you Tanim reja. How can I get rid of the backslashes?

Comment: Actually you dont need to manage backslash.. this happens because system automatically produce this slash for java string format.. and it does not make any bad effect in your code.so dont worry . system will manage it.. this thing happen during debug and log value... in actually string there is no backslash

Comment: Thanks a lot Tanim :)

Comment: Tanim can you edit your code to get a output like this [{"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"BRMS123456\nFLT22K","net_wt":"10","gross_wt":"10","stone_amt":"0","rate":"29000","making":"999","qty":"1","net_rate":"29999.0","item_total":"29999.0","sum_total":"30299.0","stone_wt":"0"},
 {"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"BRMS\nGA24K","net_wt":"10","gross_wt":"1","stone_amt":"0","rate":"32000","making":"100","qty":"1","net_rate":"","item_total":"","sum_total":"30299.0","stone_wt":""}]

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the changed jsonObject again in array
try this code

### CODE

```
   try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(
                "{  \r\n         \"itembarcode\":\"BRMS\",\r\n         \"weight\":\"10\",\r\n         \"gross_wt\":\"1\",\r\n         \"stone_amt\":\"0\",\r\n         \"s\u200C\u200Btone_wt\":\"\",\r\n         \"rate\":\"32000\",\r\n         \"making\":\"100\",\r\n         \"qty\":\"1\",\r\n         \"net_rate\":\"32100.0\",\r\n         \"item_to\u200C\u200Btal\":\"32100.0\",\r\n         \"sum_total\":\"64600.0\"\r\n      }");
        JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(
                "{  \r\n         \"itembarcode\":\"MSAA0015\",\r\n         \"weight\":\"10\",\r\n         \"gross_wt\":\"11\",\r\n         \"stone_amt\":\"100000\",\r\n         \"st\u200C\u200Bone_wt\":\"\",\r\n         \"rate\":\"32000\",\r\n         \"making\":\"500\",\r\n         \"qty\":\"1\",\r\n         \"net_rate\":\"32500.0\",\r\n         \"item_tot\u200C\u200Bal\":\"32500.0\",\r\n         \"sum_total\":\"64600.0\"\r\n      }");
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject1);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject2);
        JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
        finalObject.put("result", jsonArray);
        System.out.println("Old----->" + finalObject);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            json.put("doc_no", "IN1001");
            jsonArray.put(i, json);
            finalObject.put("result", jsonArray);
        }
        System.out.println("New----->" + finalObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

### Output

```
Old----->{"result":[{"sum_total":"64600.0","making":"100","stone_amt":"0","rate":"32000","qty":"1","weight":"10","net_rate":"32100.0","gross_wt":"1","item_to\u200c\u200btal":"32100.0","s\u200c\u200btone_wt":"","itembarcode":"BRMS"},{"sum_total":"64600.0","making":"500","stone_amt":"100000","item_tot\u200c\u200bal":"32500.0","rate":"32000","qty":"1","st\u200c\u200bone_wt":"","weight":"10","net_rate":"32500.0","gross_wt":"11","itembarcode":"MSAA0015"}]}
New----->{"result":[{"sum_total":"64600.0","making":"100","stone_amt":"0","rate":"32000","qty":"1","doc_no":"IN1001","weight":"10","net_rate":"32100.0","gross_wt":"1","item_to\u200c\u200btal":"32100.0","s\u200c\u200btone_wt":"","itembarcode":"BRMS"},{"sum_total":"64600.0","making":"500","stone_amt":"100000","item_tot\u200c\u200bal":"32500.0","rate":"32000","qty":"1","doc_no":"IN1001","st\u200c\u200bone_wt":"","weight":"10","net_rate":"32500.0","gross_wt":"11","itembarcode":"MSAA0015"}]}
```

**EDIT** I didn't realise that there is one more jsonObject:)

Comment: Thank you.I tried this but it did not give me the desired output.
This is what I want to achieve.
{"result":[{"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"BRMS","weight":"10","gross_wt":"1","stone_amt":"0","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"100","qty":"1","net_rate":"32100.0","item_total":"32100.0","sum_total":"64600.0"},
{"doc_no":"IN1001","itembarcode":"MSAA0015","weight":"10","gross_wt":"11","stone_amt":"100000","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"500","qty":"1","net_rate":"32500.0","item_total":"32500.0","sum_total":"64600.0"}]}

Comment: This is what my current array looks like.  
{"result":[{"itembarcode":"BRMS","weight":"10","gross_wt":"1","stone_amt":"0","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"100","qty":"1","net_rate":"32100.0","item_total":"32100.0","sum_total":"64600.0"},
{"itembarcode":"MSAA0015","weight":"10","gross_wt":"11","stone_amt":"100000","stone_wt":"","rate":"32000","making":"500","qty":"1","net_rate":"32500.0","item_total":"32500.0","sum_total":"64600.0"}]}